# Create Random Tree in R

Tags: r

Suppose that I want to create in `R` a binary tree on the interval `(0,1)` with maximum depth `3` in the following way:

First we have a pool of potential cut-offs for the tree `t=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7)`, a cut-off means that if we randomly choose the value `0.4` then we split the interval `(0,1)` to `(0,0.4)` and `(0.4,1)`.

The steps that I want to do are:

1)Start with the whole interval `(0,1)`

2)Randomly choose a cut-off from `t`, denoted as `t_1`

3)Split the interval `(0,1)` based on the chosen cut-off i.e. to subintervals `(0,t_1)` and `(t_1,1)`

4)Then randomly choose one of the intervals `(0,t_1)` and `(t_1,1)`

5)For the chosen interval randomly sample from the cut-offs a point `t_2` that makes sense, i.e. a point that it is not outside of the interval

6)Continue the procedure up to the point where we reach the maximum depth.

I'm totally clueless on where how to start. Is this the right forum to post such a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a tree structure like this requires a recursive function (i.e. a function that calls itself). The following function creates a list of nodes, where each branch node contains a `split` value, and two daughter nodes called `left` and `right`. The leaf nodes contains the final range encompassed within the leaf.

```r
make_node <- function(min = 0, max = 1, desired_depth = 3, depth = 0) {
  
  if (depth < desired_depth) {
    split <- runif(1, min, max)
  list(split = split, 
       left = make_node(min, split, desired_depth, depth + 1),
       right = make_node(split, max, desired_depth, depth + 1))
  } else {
    list(range = c(min, max))
  }
}
```

It works like this. Let's create a reproducible tree:

```
set.seed(1)

tree <- make_node()
```

To get the initial splitting value, we do:

```
tree$split
#> [1] 0.2655087
```

So the right branch deals with all values between 0.2655087 and 1. To see where it splits this range, we do

```
tree$right$split
#> [1] 0.4136423
```

So this branch splits into values between [0.2655087, 0.4136423] on the left and [0.4136423, 1] on the right. Let's examine the left node:

```
tree$right$left$split
#> [1] 0.3985904
```

This has now split the [0.2655087, 0.4136423] branch into a left [0.2655087, 0.3985904] branch and a right [0.3985904, 0.4136423] branch.

If we take this right branch, have now reached depth 3, so we get the final range of this leaf and confirm its range:

```
tree$right$left$right
#> $range
#> [1] 0.3985904 0.4136423
```

Of course, to make all this easier you probably want some kind of function to walk the tree to classify a particular number.

```r
walk_tree <- function(value, tree) {
  result <- paste("Value:", value, "\n")
  while(is.null(tree$range)) {
    if(value >= tree$split) {
      result <- paste(result, "\nGreater than split of", tree$split)
      tree <- tree$right
    } else {
      result <- paste(result, "\nLess than split of", tree$split)
      tree <- tree$left
    }
  }
  result <- paste0(result, "\nValue falls into leaf node with range [",
                  tree$range[1], ",", tree$range[2], "]\n")
  cat(result)
}
```

So, for example, we get

```r
walk_tree(value = 0.4, tree)
#> Value: 0.4 
#>  
#> Greater than split of 0.2655086631421 
#> Less than split of 0.413642294289884 
#> Greater than split of 0.398590389362078
#> Value falls into leaf node with range [0.398590389362078,0.413642294289884]
```

You may prefer that this function returns a vector of 0s and 1s, or you may be looking for it to draw the tree, which is trickier to do, but possible.

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding - though as usual not as succinct as your answer (+1). It still hurts my head a bit to write a recursive function, and using a debugger on a recursion function makes it hurt even more.

Comment: @AllanCameron That's a really smart answer!! Just to clarify because I've never used a recursive function in R, my question is why you don't use all the arguments when you run the ```make_node ```, i.e. why you dont use also the maximun depth argument?

Comment: @Jonathan1234 that's a good point. The desired depth should be passed to the internal function calls otherwise they always deafult to a depth of 3. I'll fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps we can use `Reduce` to generate intervals in the binary-tree manner

```
Reduce(
  function(interval, k) {
    lb <- min(interval)
    ub <- max(interval)
    x <- v[v > lb & v < ub]
    if (!length(x)) {
      return(c(NA, NA))
    }
    p <- sample(x, 1)
    list(c(lb, p), c(p, ub))[[sample(1:2, 1)]]
  },
  1:3,
  init = c(0, 1),
  accumulate = TRUE
)
```

and you will see the result like

```
[[1]]
[1] 0 1

[[2]]
[1] 0.0 0.6

[[3]]
[1] 0.0 0.2

[[4]]
[1] 0.0 0.1
```

which indicates the selected interval in each iteration from top to bottom.